# Delaying execution of multiple HTTP requests in Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I've implemented a web scraper with Nodejs, cheerio and request-promise that scrapes an endpoint (basic html page) and return certain information. The content of the page I'm crawling differs based on a parameter at the end of the url (http://some-url.com?value=12345 where 12345 is my dynamic value).

I need this crawler to work every x minutes and crawl multiple pages, and to do that I've set a cronjob using Google Cloud Scheduler. (I'm fetching the dynamic values I need from Firebase).

There could be more than 50 different values for which I'd need to crawl the specific page, but I would like to ease the load with which I'm sending the requests so the server doesn't choke. To accomplish this, I've tried to add a delay

1) using setTimeout

2) using setInterval

3) using a custom sleep implementation:

```
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);
```

**All 3 of these methods work locally**; all of the requests are made with y seconds delay as intended.

But when tried with Firebase Cloud Functions and Google Cloud Scheduler

1) not all of the requests are sent

2) the delay is NOT consistent (some requests fire with the proper delay, then there are no requests made for a while and other requests are sent with a major delay)

I've tried many things but I wasn't able to solve this problem. 
I was wondering if anyone could suggest a different theoretical approach or a certain library etc. I can take for this scenario, since the one I have now doesn't seem to work as I intended. I'm adding one of the approaches that locally work below.

Cheers!

```
  courseDataRefArray.forEach(async (dataRefObject: CourseDataRef, index: number) => {
    console.log(`Foreach index = ${index} -- Hello StackOverflow`);

    setTimeout(async () => {
      console.log(`Index in setTimeout = ${index} -- Hello StackOverflow`);
      await CourseUtil.initiateJobForCourse(dataRefObject.ref, dataRefObject.data);
    }, 2000 * index);

  });
```

(Note: I can provide more code samples if necessary; but it's mostly following a loop & async/await & setTimeout pattern, and since it works locally I'm assuming that's not the main problem.)

Comment: Seeking recommendations for solutions is off topic for Stack Overflow.  If you'd like to drum up some conversation about ways to architect this project, I'll suggest posing to Reddit to get some advice.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the feedback, I've now also posted my question over there.